# Too many spaces between CREATE and PROCEDURE after I script it AS CREATE (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, alter

I have a stored procedure that and when I script it as Create it looks normal
`CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcedureName]`, but after i run `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [ProcedureName]` and script it again It looks like this `CREATE   PROCEDURE [ProcedureName]`. There is 2 additional spaces and the schema compare catch this as difference. Maybe It is configuration in SSMS or something else. Does anyone bumped into this?

Comment: Remove the `OR` and `ALTER` and you get the same result. When the definition is stored in SQL Server it is just removing those keywords. If you wrote `CREATE    OR     ALTER PROCEDURE` and then use the "Create To" feature (or used `sys.sp_helptext`), you'd get `CREATE          PROCEDURE`

Comment: We always use `CREATE` for clear DB and `CREATE OR ALTER` for migration, but this is the only place that there is such a problem

Comment: Why do you care? If your concern is because you are comparing raw SQL text for schema comparison purposes, don't do that. Use a database compare tool, such as the one included with Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using compare in VS, the issue is from work and I have a task to fix it

Comment: This is by design, and it's not the only place this happens in, it's the limitation of how the server processes create or alter.

Comment: You should script it as `CREATE OR ALTER` always, even when creating it.